# PGSQL: Function argument not being passed correctly

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I am attempting to search the "message" column of a table for any instance of a tag mentioned (like " #testing1 " for example).

When I manually enter the query it works but I think that I'm not understanding how to concat the tag properly:

This works:

```sql
select amount from donations where message like #testing1
```

But this does not:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_tag(
    tag TEXT) 
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    select amount from donations where message like CONCAT ('%#', tag, '%');
END; $$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The above is what is in the begin and end statements inside of the function `sum_tag(tag text)`.

My intent is that I am trying to capture the tag whether it is in the message as "#testing1 this is a message" or "This is a message #testing1" and then use that as an identifier to sum up all of the amount column values for the associated rows.

Update 1

> I have attempted to use [the suggestion as noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450660/pgsql-function-argument-not-being-passed-correctly?noredirect=1#comment131428351_74450660) but It did not seem to work. The updated function was entered as:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_tag(
    tag TEXT) 
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('select amount from donations where message like %s', tag);
END; $$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> This did not work either. If I am understanding, the entire statement needs to be in single quotes and `%s` is the correct way to call the argument as it is a text string. I appreciate your explanation and places to look.

Comment: 1) You need to add the actual function code to your question. 2) Also look at [Dynamic queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in particular the part about using [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

Comment: `where message like #testing1` should not work. Did you actually do `where message like '#testing1'`? And did you mean `where message like '%#testing1%'`?

Comment: As the docs said, *In addition to the format specifiers described above, the special sequence %% may be used to output a literal % character.*. So: `format('select amount from donations where message like  %%%s%%', '#testing1')` to end up with `select amount from donations where message like %#testing1%`

Comment: Your `sum_tag`'s return type is void, but how are you verifying that it does not work? Does it throw an error?